# OpenCV Python detect black rectangular area of film and draw contour around frame

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I am trying to use opencv and python to detect the edges of a film frame to know it is in position to snap a picture with my raspberry pi camera. My plan is to detect the edges of a frame that must be of a minimum size so that I know I have an actual frame in view for the camera.  I have tried setting thresholds with lower values but since the image is of black and white film everything seems to merge together.

I've tried cropping the original image to focus on the area of interest and work from there but  the colors just blend together without much separation.

```
# load the image
image = cv2.imread('clip1.jpg')

image = image[200:1000, 300:1300]

# Greyscale, blur, find edges
grayscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh = cv2.threshold(grayscale_image, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Original image:

[image]

What I would like to accomplish (green contours with x,y,w,h coordinates):

[image]

The problem with detecting the white rectangles is that the poor condition of the film/images makes these rectangles not consistent also.  In the first image there are what appear to be two rectangles, in this last image there appear to be four and they are blurred together.  There are various other inconsistencies like this that make the rectangles difficult to work with on both the top and bottom of the film clip which leads me to believe working with the black edges around the desired clip is my best option.  Below is the poor quality rectangle image.

[image: Poor quality rectangle image.]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe it would be simpler to detect white rectangle below frame and use its location to crop black frame.

Comment: agreed, locate the holes

Comment: The issue with that is the film is in poor condition near the holes throughout the reel but the dark edges along the frame of single clips seem to be consistent.

Comment: please show us such "poor condition" data. we can't deal with what we can't see.

Comment: Please see my most recent edit above.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: the first film appears to have one punch per frame, the second film has two "not quite" punches between those. I also see some debris *in* the true punches. what's with that? back light also seems inconsistent, blowing out the bottom line of punches.

Comment: There are two punches per frame.  There are also incosistencies with lighting and image collection.  Is there a possibility to draw contours with black edges around the gray clip?

Comment: might be doable. inrange or invert+threshold to get black to become white (foreground), then morphology operations with a very tall kernel (or wide kernel for the length-wise/horizontal parts) -- a robust solution will likely involve a lot of approaches in combination, and multi-stage processing to keep the results smooth. for videos, you don't want the frames to jump around just because you registered them using the holes or frame. you'd want to align the frames by content. that might be doable with ECC refinement, perhaps two stages with the first on lowpassed frames

Comment: Perhaps manually measure the usable size of the frame. Then use the outer white sprockets for alignment of that size area for cropping.

Comment: The problem is a motor is pulling the image into a view & unfortunately the tension on the film & the total movement of it through the view can vary.  Not guaranteed a consistent location of these items in relation to a point.  As they pass through the view I'd like to be able to recognize these parts/sections, their relation to pre determined coord, stop motor once they reach a desired point, snap photo, & proceed.  There are a lot of variables both mechanical & software that I have to account for.  I am hoping to find a reliable section of the image to work with in that regard.

Comment: commercial film digitization apparatus costs a lot because it's so precise. you can't hope to come close to that quality and speed with a raspberry pi camera and some 3d printed parts. you might, if you spend a lot of time on this and figure out all the problems (mechanical, optical, ...)